# How to reverse multilevel array in PHP

Tags: php

How to simply reverse this array so last record displays first and other records will arrange one by one in reverse order.

I tried `$MyArray=array_reverse($MyArray,true);` but it only moves `"status": "ok"` at top and all other records inside `products` array remain unchanged. So how can I reverse records of `products` array only and not `"status": "ok"`?

```
{
    "product": [{
        "IDs": ["00000087102110"],
        "Brand": "SONY",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "SAMSUNG",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "GPI14s": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HCL",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "GPI14s": ["00000087102110"],
        "Brand": "LG",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "GPI14s": ["00000087102120"],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Rank": 1
    }, {
        "GPI14s": ["00000087102150"],
        "Brand": "HP",
        "Rank": 1
    }],
    "status": "ok"
}
```

Comment: $MyArray["product"]=array_reverse($MyArray["product"],true); Have you tried this?

Comment: BTW while displaying you can parse the array in reverse as well instead of reversing it read it from last to first

Comment: If the point is to only loop in reverse order, then only loop from last to first instead of changing the structure.

Comment: Did you `json_decode()` this before applying `array_reverse()` ?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava, Yes I tried but under `foreach` loop so didn't work but as per your suggestion, it's working now

Comment: @Benni, yes I did

Comment: @RK Ahir, when you `print_r()` the decoded array, you see that it has two entries, "product" and "status" on the top level. `array_reverse()` will only affect the top level, so in order to reverse the products use `$MyArray['products'] = array_reverse($MyArray['products'])`

Comment: added answer below please take a look

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_merge also

```
    $json = '
    {
        "product": [{
            "IDs": ["00000087102110"],
            "Brand": "SONY",
            "Rank": 1
        }, {
            "IDs": ["00000087102120"],
            "Brand": "SAMSUNG",
            "Rank": 1
        }, {
            "GPI14s": ["00000087102150"],
            "Brand": "HCL",
            "Rank": 1
        }, {
            "GPI14s": ["00000087102110"],
            "Brand": "LG",
            "Rank": 1
        }, {
            "GPI14s": ["00000087102120"],
            "Brand": "LENOVO",
            "Rank": 1
        }, {
            "GPI14s": ["00000087102150"],
            "Brand": "HP",
            "Rank": 1
        }],
        "status": "ok"
    }';

    $decoded = json_decode($json,true);
    $reverse['product'] = array_reverse($decoded['product']);
    unset($decoded['product']);
    $reverse = array_merge($reverse,$decoded);

    echo json_encode($reverse,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and output with :

```
{
"product": [
    {
        "GPI14s": [
            "00000087102150"
        ],
        "Brand": "HP",
        "Rank": 1
    },
    {
        "GPI14s": [
            "00000087102120"
        ],
        "Brand": "LENOVO",
        "Rank": 1
    },
    {
        "GPI14s": [
            "00000087102110"
        ],
        "Brand": "LG",
        "Rank": 1
    },
    {
        "GPI14s": [
            "00000087102150"
        ],
        "Brand": "HCL",
        "Rank": 1
    },
    {
        "IDs": [
            "00000087102120"
        ],
        "Brand": "SAMSUNG",
        "Rank": 1
    },
    {
        "IDs": [
            "00000087102110"
        ],
        "Brand": "SONY",
        "Rank": 1
    }
],
"status": "ok"
}
```